# Why I'm getting duplicated resolutions values in the dropdown ui after changing resolution?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The resolutions changing is taking affect only when running the game from the built exe file.
When running the game I have 19 resolutions in the dropdown ui.

The first resolution is 640 x 480 and the last one and the current one is 2910 x 1080

[image: Resolutions]

When running the game from the built exe file and changing the resolutions for example from 640 x 480 to 720 x 480 or to 1920 x 1080 it will change the resolution but it will also duplicate the resolutions many times in the dropdown ui.

Screenshot when running the game from the exe built file. Even before changing/selecting any resolution I see them duplicated. For example the 640 x 480 is 7 times duplicated the next resultion is duplicated 5 times I think and so on...the last 1920 x 1080 is also 5 or 7 times duplicated.

It seems each resolution is duplicated few times.

But it's not duplicated in the editor only in the exe built file.

[image: When running the game from the exe built file]

The script I'm using :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SettingsMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioMixer audioMixer;
    public Text volumeInPercentages;
    public Dropdown resolutionDropDown;

    [SerializeField]
    private Slider _volumeSlider;
    [SerializeField]
    private Dropdown _dropDownQuality;

    private Resolution[] resolutions;

    private void Start()
    {
        resolutions = Screen.resolutions;
        resolutionDropDown.ClearOptions();

        List<string> options = new List<string>();

        int currentResolutionIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < resolutions.Length; i++)
        {
            string option = resolutions[i].width + " x " + resolutions[i].height;
            options.Add(option);

            if (resolutions[i].width == Screen.currentResolution.width &&
                resolutions[i].height == Screen.currentResolution.height)
            {
                currentResolutionIndex = i;
            }
        }

        resolutionDropDown.AddOptions(options);
        resolutionDropDown.value = currentResolutionIndex;
        resolutionDropDown.RefreshShownValue();
    }

    public void SetVolume()
    {
        float volume = _volumeSlider.value;
        Debug.Log("Volume " + volume);
        audioMixer.SetFloat("MusicVol", Mathf.Log10(volume) * 20);
        volumeInPercentages.text = Mathf.Round(volume * 100).ToString() + " %";
    }

    public void SetQuality()
    {
        int qualityIndex = _dropDownQuality.value;
        QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel(qualityIndex);
    }

    public void SetFullScreen()
    {
        Screen.fullScreen = !Screen.fullScreen;
    }

    public void SetResolution()
    {
        Resolution resolution = resolutions[resolutionDropDown.value];
        Screen.SetResolution(resolution.width, resolution.height, Screen.fullScreen);
    }
}
```

And a screenshot of the ui dropdown inspector settings :

[image: Dropdown ui inspector settings]

The SettingsMenu script is attached to the Canvas under the Main Menu.

Comment: Looks like you are starting the re-filling of the UI element before you have cleaned it. You only need to fill it on *first* showing. Not every time afterwards. | Propably the single instance of `SettingsMenu` is kept - including `public Dropdown resolutionDropDown;`, but Start is recalled on the later showing.

Comment: The problem was that it's not showing duplicated resolutions but the same resolutions with a different framerate.  It seems in the end that just changing the string line to this solved the problem : string option = resolutions[i].width + " x " + resolutions[i].height
                 + " " + resolutions[i].refreshRate.ToString() + " Hz";
            options.Add(option);

Comment: A screenshot in the link of how the resolutions dropdown looks like now after changed the string line : https://imgur.com/a/L0dJLiU

Comment: It's just in the editor it didn't show "duplicated" resolutions only when running from the built exe file. And then in the built exe file it's showing all the framerates for each resolution so it looks like duplicated but it's not.

Comment: I trust the Editor Preview was far as I can throw it. And it is bits in my computer, so ahrd to get a hold off :) It is just that - a preview. Only the actually running of the Code can be the deciding factor. | I missread it as "it shows the proper amount on first call, but duplicates on all others."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because Unity differentiates between different refresh rates for the same resolution.

For example:
640x480 @60Hz is a separate resolution option from 640x480 @144Hz.

You can't see this easily if you're displaying only the height and width of the display, but debugging does reveal that this is the case.

I've had this issue before and my fix for this was to keep track of the Width and Height when adding options to the dropdown.

My solution was to cache the width and height of the resolution and compare it to the next option's width and height. If either was different I'd cache that, add a new option and then continue iterating over the options.

You can see [in the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resolution.html) that the `Resolution` also contains the field for `refreshRate`.